# In Dynamics 365 with Unified Interface, could I create a manged solution to customize the Sales Hub App?

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365, dynamics-365-sales, dynamics365-app-mobile

Context: this is for an ISV that sells extended Lead information. we have created web resources ( HTML , javascript) etc that will fetch the data from our REST API and render it in our HTML. I want to put a tab on the lead details page to render this data. Our mangaged solution was working for the class "web" interface version but now our users prefer to use the Sales Hub app.

My understanding is that the sales hub app is itself a managed solution. So I am wondering if it is possible to customize the pages on this app.

Answer (score 0):

when I had posted this question , I did not know much about dynamics 365. after some trial and error, I have found that when a custom solution includes a entity form .e.g contacts form and has customization for the form, that customization will appear in the sales hub app.